# Composer with separated directories?

Tags: directory, composer-php, package

I'm a software developer and frequently jump from a project to another and I have a problem with Composer.

If I have 2 separated projects, each of them need a package from composer (and it's dependancies) and each of them goes on vendor, then I'll have a vendor directory full of junk. 
That's bad.

So how can I ask composer to install package A on vendorA and package B on vendorB? It's a simple concept but every test I did and every search I've done was useless.

Can someone have the solution? If Composer is so wide used it should be a little less dull damn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found already. I post the solution hoping to help other people.
I use hostgator shared account, if you use something else things may differ a little.

Let's say we have /home3/user/project/app.php
app.php need swiftmailer package for some reason and we don't want to put it with the rest of the packages on /home/vendor.
So we are gonna put it there: /home/user/project

Standard command

**composer require swiftmailer/swiftmailer**

OUR command with personalized directory:

**composer require swiftmailer/swiftmailer -d /home3/user/project**

Hope this help someone.